# MaxMin Function within Select Statement SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am having a few issues making a MAX function work within the select statement See example data below:

```
Table 1                   Table 2
Visit_ID Car_ID        Move_ID  Visit_ID  MoveStartDate  MoveEndDate
A          1              1        A      25/07/2016     27/07/2016 
B          2              2        A      28/07/2016     28/07/2016   
C          1              3        B      19/07/2016     22/07/2016 
D          3              4        D      28/06/2016     30/06/2016
```

I would like my select statement to pick the min start time and Max start time based on the Visit_ID so I would be expecting:

```
Result
Visit_ID   Car_ID  StartDate   EndDate
A           1      25/07/2016  28/07/2016
B           2      19/07/2016  22/07/2016
```

So far I have tried I already have Inner Joins in my select statement:

```
,(MAX (EndDate) WHERE Visit.Visit_ID = Move.Visit_ID) AS End Date
```

I have looked at some other queries with a second select statement within the select so you end up with something like:

```
Select Visit_ID, Car_ID ,(Select MAX(EndDate) FULL OUTER JOIN Table 2 ON Table 1.Visit_ID = Table 2.Visit_ID Group By Table 1.Visit_ID) AS End Date
```

Hope I have provided enough info currently stumped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Consider adding to the query the difference (end-start) making an outer select that would pick the max and min of that difference.

Comment: Why no Car_ID = 3 in the result?

Comment: @jarlh Yes I meant to include that in the result. This is only a snippet of a table.

Comment: @Dunny774, can't you adjust the expected result, so it reflects the sample data?

Answer (score 1):

If you also want Car_ID = 3 in the result:

```
select t1.Visit_ID, t1.Car_ID, MIN(MoveStartDate), MAX(MoveEndDate)
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.Visit_ID = t2.Visit_ID
group by t1.Visit_ID, t1.Car_ID
```

Returns:

```
SQL>select t1.Visit_ID, t1.Car_ID, MIN(MoveStartDate), MAX(MoveEndDate)
SQL&from table1 t1
SQL&  join table2 t2 on t1.Visit_ID = t2.Visit_ID
SQL&group by t1.Visit_ID, t1.Car_ID;

visit_id      car_id
======== =========== ==================== ====================
A                  1 25/07/2016           28/07/2016
B                  2 19/07/2016           22/07/2016
D                  3 28/06/2016           30/06/2016

                  3 rows found
```

Comment: Thanks for the response unfortunately I am seeing Column errors of 'column name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either aggregate function or the group by clause.

Comment: @Dunny774, very odd. Are you really executing my SELECT, or something similar/adjusted?

Comment: I have managed to get the subquery to work but with a new error of subquery returning more than one value

Comment: Subquery? Is this just a small part of a bigger query? (This is an answer to the question asked above. If you want to know something else, ask another question.)

Comment: What I have down at the moment:

Comment: What I have down at the moment:
'Select t1.Car_id, t1.Car_name, t1.Car_Reg
,(Select Min(t2.MoveEndDate) from dbo.move as t2 Inner Join t1 on t2.Visit_id = t1.Visit_ID' Where t2.Visit_ID = t1.Visitid) As 'Arrive time'

At the moment  it complains that it will return multiple values, if I put Select top 1 it returns the record but in pairs where one with the field complete and other as null.

Comment: Move the sub-query from the `SELECT` list to the `FROM` clause. I.e. do a `JOIN` instead!

Comment: Could you please provide an example I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: Ask another question. Showing us the whole query that doesn't work.

Comment: I'll put another question on with more complete code and stuff on

Comment: Please see:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656419/min-max-subquery-issue?noredirect=1#comment64694030_38656419)

Answer (score 1):

I did not check it but your can try this

```
WITH cte
AS
(select Move_ID,Visit_ID,min(MoveStartDate) AS mMS,MAX(MoveEndDate) AS mME
 FROM Table_2
 GROUP BY Move_ID,Visit_ID)

 SELECT c.Move_ID,c.Visit_ID,T1.Car_ID,c.mMS,c.mME
 FROM Table_1 as T1 JOIN cte as C
 ON c.Visit_ID=T1.Visit_ID
```