# Min/Max Subquery issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a few issues with a subquery error as it wishes to pull multiple results:
Full query:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000
       Visit.BookingNumber AS 'Booking Number'
      ,Car.Name AS 'Car Name'
      ,Car.REGNumber AS 'REG Number'
      ,Type.Name AS 'Car Type'
      ,Car.[Length]
      ,Car.GrossTonnage
      ,Loc.Name AS 'Space'
      ,CAST ( 
            CASE WHEN Loc.Name = 'Zone 6' or Loc.Name = 'Zone 7'
                THEN 'Terminal 2' ELSE 'Terminal 1'
                END AS nvarchar) AS 'Terminal'

      ,(SELECT  MIN (VisitMove.ActualStopDateUTC) FROM [CarDB].[dbo].[CarMovement] 

      INNER JOIN  dbo.Visit ON CarMovement.Visit_GUID = Visit.Visit_GUID 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Location AS Loc ON CarMovement.MovementToLocation_GUID = Loc.Location_GUID

      WHERE  Visit.Visit_GUID = CarMovement.Visit_GUID and CarMovement.MovementType_ID = '1' and  Loc.Name in ('Zone 8' , 'Zone 9' , 'Zone 7' , 'Zone 6') 
      GROUP BY CarMovement.Visit_GUID)AS 'Arrive Time'

      --,MAX (VisitMove.ActualStopDateUTC) AS 'Finish Time'

  FROM [CarDB].[dbo].[Visit] AS Visit 

  INNER JOIN dbo.Car AS Car ON Visit.Car_GUID = Car.Car_GUID
  INNER JOIN dbo.CarMovement AS CarMove ON Visit.Visit_GUID = CarMove.Visit_GUID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Location AS Loc ON CarMove.MovementToLocation_GUID = Loc.Location_GUID
  INNER JOIN dbo.CarType AS Type ON Car.CarType_ID = Type.CarType_ID

  WHERE Loc.Name in ('Zone 8' , 'Zone 9' , 'Zone 7' , 'Zone 6')

  GROUP BY 
  Visit.BookingNumber, 
  Car.Name, 
  Car.IMONumber, 
  Type.Name, 
  Car.[Length], 
  Car.GrossTonnage,
  Loc.Name, 
  Visit.Visit_GUID, 
  CarMove.MovementType_ID, 
 CarMove.ActualStopDateUTC
```

The subquery I am having issues with:

```
(SELECT  MIN (VisitMove.ActualStopDateUTC) FROM [CarDB].[dbo].[CarMovement] 

  INNER JOIN  dbo.Visit ON CarMovement.Visit_GUID = Visit.Visit_GUID 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Location AS Loc ON CarMovement.MovementToLocation_GUID = Loc.Location_GUID

  WHERE  Visit.Visit_GUID = VisitMovement.Visit_GUID and CarMovement.MovementType_ID = '1' and  Loc.Name in ('Zone 8' , 'Zone 9' , 'Zone 7' , 'Zone 6') 
  GROUP BY CarMovement.Visit_GUID)AS 'Arrive Time'
```

Our table setup up is a there is a visit table and a car movements table with a one to many relationship (A visit can have many car movements) I am trying to create two subqueries (just focusing on getting one to work now) to pull the Min(Earliest) stop date from the car movement list and the Max(last) stop date all based on the visit_guid. Unfortunately I think my sub query is unable to identify just one field/record per visit_id and instead trying to pull all stop dates into the table. ( I identified this by running the query on its own and it pull all dates back.)

Any ideas?

Comment: This subquery is in your select list.  AFAIK unless it returns a single value for each outer record, you will get an error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have changed the joins inside the query to FULL OUTER and it still returns the same issue,
I have also tried Select Top 1 but it seems to return the records in pairs instead.

Comment: You might have missed the idea in my comment.  I was saying that your _outer_ select list has a subquery returning multiple records.  This needs to be fixed.  Can you update it to restrict to a single result?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I assume (looking at internet resources you mean a select Column1 column2  from ( Select date1, date2 From carmove)
Where  loc.name = 'zone 8'

Comment: select min from subquery

Answer (score 2):

A `GROUP BY` in a scalar subquery is highly suspect.  Basically, it should never be there.  Why?  A scalar subquery can return at most one row.  A `GROUP BY` suggests that there a multiple groups -- and hence multiple rows.

So, I would suggest:

```
(SELECT  MIN(VisitMove.ActualStopDateUTC)
 FROM [CarDB].[dbo].[CarMovement] INNER JOIN
      dbo.Visit
      ON CarMovement.Visit_GUID = Visit.Visit_GUID INNER JOIN
      dbo.Location AS Loc
      ON CarMovement.MovementToLocation_GUID = Loc.Location_GUID
 WHERE Visit.Visit_GUID = VisitMovement.Visit_GUID and 
       CarMovement.MovementType_ID = '1' and
       Loc.Name in ('Zone 8' , 'Zone 9' , 'Zone 7' , 'Zone 6') 
) as [Arrive Time]
```

I'm not 100% sure that this will fix all your problems.  But this is likely to be one of them.

Comment: Hi Gordon, One step closer! it is now returning records (in pairs) and it has pulled back the first entry in the entire table and written it to every record. I assume its down to ID'ing the correct visit_guid to the time as it appears to not be doing that... :/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT V.*, MOVE.* FROM VISIT V
                OUTER APPLY 
                   (SELECT TOP 1 M.* CarMovement M 
                                       WHERE M.GUID = V.GUID 
                                         ORDER BY M.YourDate ASC) AS MOVE
```

that's saying, take your single record from VISIT, then try and find the TOP 1 Ordered by Date (if there are any records - null otherwise)

you can then do the same for MAX Date by creating a second 'outer apply' ordering by DATE DESC

that's not all the query, just a skeleton of how to link a single Visit to the first one of movement

Comment: I have tried writing it in I seem to get incorrect syntax error:  near 'Arrive Time' Expecting ID or Quoted ID. Tried removing the AS statement form the outer apply but it moves the INNER JOIN below.

Comment: I'd recommend starting from scratch and seeing if you can retrieve your visit record joined to the corresponding TOP 1 Record belonging to carMovement, then building it from there

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the sub-query was not required.

It was the method I grouped the records, hence why I said in a previous comment I was receiving some records in pairs.

I had grouped the records looking at Unique IDs.

My bad :)

Thanks for all assistance provided.